# Run lambda function after all other lambdas have completed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

I'm wondering if anyone knows of any way to run a lambda function after all other lambda functions have completed/stopped. I've looked into AWS Step Functions but it doesn't seem to fit my use case, or if it does I'm not sure how to go about it.

For context, I am trying to cache some project details after all records, or new records, have been inserted into the database. The flow I'm trying to achieve looks a bit like this:

[image]

Is something like this possible? If not, any other recommendations (like cron-jobs)? I'm using MongoDB (Atlas) if that's any help as well.

Any advice would be appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why AWS Step Functions is not fitting for this use case? It supports both sequential dependency and also parallel executions

Comment: From what I researched, I didn't see a way to trigger Step Functions from a batch S3 upload. A single file would count as an event, that would then trigger multiple Step Function instances. Is that incorrect? I did research but not a ton.

Comment: Ok, one possible way is to notify an SNS topic once the batch of files is uploaded to S3 and have Step Functions triggered and read the files from S3 instead of S3 Event trigger. This would allow clients to know once all S3 files are uploaded. And, Step Function can iterate over the files so that a single lambda can process all the files (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/tutorial-create-iterate-pattern-section.html) and then call the final lambda function. This helps to keep everything stateless

Comment: Oh ya, that could work! Could you by chance point me in the direction of how to notify SNS once a batch of files has uploaded? I'm able to see that it's possible, just not how to go about setting it up.

Comment: That has to be done by the same source which uploads the S3 files, once s3 batch upload is complete, additional call has to be made to insert a message to an SNS topic

Comment: Ah I see. So there is no way to do it via the AWS S3 console UI?

Answer (score 1):

This may be what your looking for: (Once you merge the results you could run another lambda of your choice)

```json
{
  "Comment": "Parallel Example.",
  "StartAt": "Process S3",
  "States": {
    "Process S3": {
      "Type": "Parallel",
      "Next": "Merge Results",
      "Branches": [
        {
         "StartAt": "Upload S3 A",
         "States": {
           "Upload S3 A": {
             "Type": "Task",
             "Resource":
               "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:123456789012:function:foobar",
             "Next": "Process S3 A"
           },
           "Process S3 A": {
             "Type": "Task",
             "Resource":
               "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:123456789012:function:foobar",
             "End": true
           }
         }
       },
       {
         "StartAt": "Upload S3 B",
         "States": {
                      "Upload S3 B": {
             "Type": "Task",
             "Resource":
               "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:123456789012:function:foobar",
             "Next": "Process S3 B"
           },
           "Process S3 B": {
             "Type": "Task",
             "Resource":
               "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:123456789012:function:foobar",
             "End": true
           }
         }
       }
      ]
    },
    "Merge Results":{
                 "Type": "Task",
             "Resource":
               "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:123456789012:function:foobar",
             "End":true
  }
  }
}
```

[image: Diagram]